# contenteditable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just learned about `contenteditable` and I would like to use it in [my project here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/120/).

So, I have commented out `on("click", ..)` for `<p>` and I have added that attribute to it in the HTML.

But, the content is not editable. I am not sure why it is not working. I also added the `DOCTYPE` but it made no difference. There is not error in the console.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/120/)

**EDIT:**
*Recreating the problem:* Try adding an item with the `Add` button. Now, if you click on the newly added item, it should be editable, but it isnt.

Comment: @Teemu Please see my edit above.

Comment: But _it is editable_ (FF30) ... Is this happening in a specific browser only?

Comment: @Teemu I'm using FF30 and it isn't editable when I create a new item and try to edit the item I've created.

Comment: @RahulDesai Looking at the developer console, it looks like when I'm clicking on the text after adding a new item, it's hitting the `<li>` and not the `<p>`

Comment: Yea, your ui.sortable is blocking access.

Comment: @Teemu He's not having trouble with editing new items after adding them, he's having problems with editing the items he's already added, e.g. the top item in your screenshot

Comment: "`Now, if you click on the newly added item, it should be editable, but it isn't.`" This made me to think something else. But indeed, the older tasks can't be edited.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had to explicitly add `focus` to the `p` using the `onclick` event.
Should be working: http://jsfiddle.net/csTS7/130/

See line 209:

```
"<p class='item_content' contenteditable='true' onclick='$(this).focus();'>"+$("#new_todo_item").val()+"</p>"
```

---

### Update:

I just noticed you mentioning that you commented out the onclick event. If you uncomment that and change the contents to `$(this).focus();` it will function as expected.

Either solution works, but the latter is cleaner.

Comment: Please check this fiddle in Chrome (possibly v35): http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/196/ If I edit an element and click in the white space in between the text and the star, the editability doesnt go away. It works in Firefox v30 though. How do I make it work in Chrome?

Comment: Within function "addItem" on line 261, I've added a `div` with class "clearClick". Also at the top of the CSS, I've put the attributes of said class. This essentially breaks off the end of your `contenteditable` `p` element. http://jsfiddle.net/csTS7/227/

Comment: The problem still persists though.

Comment: @StaticVoid Thak you for help!

Comment: actually you could directly use `this.focus()`